Are there infinitely many $g$- or $m$-primes?
I will use the definition of $f_n(x)$ from here. Let us call a number $n$ a g-number (g = for "gerade = even" in German) if for all $x\in \mathbb{R}: f_n(x)=f_n(-x)$.
Let us call a number $n$ a u-number if (u = for "ungerade = odd " in German) for all $x \in \mathbb{R}: f_n(x) = -f_n(-x)$. A number , which is neither a g- or a u- number will be called m-number. Examples:
n, Type, f_n(x)
1 G 1
2 U x
3 M x + 1
4 G x^2
5 G x^2 + 1
6 M x^2 + x
7 M x^2 + x + 1
8 U x^3
9 M x^2 + 2*x + 1
10 U x^3 + x
11 M x^3 + x + 1
12 M x^3 + x^2
13 M x^3 + x^2 + 1
14 M x^3 + x^2 + x
15 M x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
16 G x^4
17 G x^4 + 1
18 M x^3 + 2*x^2 + x
19 M x^3 + 2*x^2 + x + 1
20 G x^4 + x^2
21 M x^3 + 2*x^2 + 2*x + 1
22 M x^4 + x^2 + x
23 M x^4 + x^2 + x + 1
24 M x^4 + x^3
25 G x^4 + 2*x^2 + 1
26 M x^4 + x^3 + x
27 M x^3 + 3*x^2 + 3*x + 1
28 M x^4 + x^3 + x^2
29 M x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1
30 M x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x
31 M x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
32 U x^5
33 M x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 2*x + 1
34 U x^5 + x
35 M x^4 + x^3 + 2*x^2 + x + 1
36 M x^4 + 2*x^3 + x^2
37 M x^4 + 2*x^3 + x^2 + 1
38 M x^4 + 2*x^3 + x^2 + x
39 M x^4 + 2*x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
40 U x^5 + x^3
41 M x^5 + x^3 + 1
42 M x^4 + 2*x^3 + 2*x^2 + x
43 M x^4 + 2*x^3 + 2*x^2 + x + 1
44 M x^5 + x^3 + x^2
45 M x^4 + 2*x^3 + 2*x^2 + 2*x + 1
46 M x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x
47 M x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
48 M x^5 + x^4
49 M x^4 + 2*x^3 + 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1
50 U x^5 + 2*x^3 + x
51 M x^5 + x^4 + x + 1
52 M x^5 + x^4 + x^2
53 M x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1
54 M x^4 + 3*x^3 + 3*x^2 + x
55 M x^5 + 2*x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
56 M x^5 + x^4 + x^3
57 M x^4 + 3*x^3 + 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1
58 M x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x
59 M x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1
60 M x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2
61 M x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1
62 M x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x
63 M x^4 + 3*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 3*x + 1
64 G x^6

Question 1: Are there infinitely many g-primes?
What I think that I can prove:
Observing the factorization of $p-1$ if $p$ is a g-prime, then one sees a pattern:
5 2^2
17 2^4
101 2^2 * 5^2
257 2^8
401 2^4 * 5^2
1361 2^4 * 5 * 17
1601 2^6 * 5^2
5441 2^6 * 5 * 17
6869 2^2 * 17 * 101
8081 2^4 * 5 * 101
8501 2^2 * 5^3 * 17
17477 2^2 * 17 * 257
25601 2^10 * 5^2
28901 2^2 * 5^2 * 17^2
32321 2^6 * 5 * 101
62501 2^2 * 5^6
65537 2^16
82241 2^6 * 5 * 257
87041 2^10 * 5 * 17


Using known properties of even, odd and mixed polynomial functions with natural numbers as coefficients we can write a table:




+
G
U
M




G
G
M
M


U
M
U
M


M
M
M
M



and similarily:



*
G
U
M




G
G
U
M


U
U
G
M


M
M
M
M




The observed pattern I think I can prove:
$p$ is a g-prime

$\iff$
$$p-1 = 2^{2k} \prod_{q \neq 2, q\mid p-1,q \in \mathbb{G}} q^{v_q(p-1)}$$
for a natural number $k$, where $\mathbb{G}$  denotes the subset of the natural number which are g-numbers.

$n$ is a g-number, iff $n = 2^{2k} \prod_{p\neq2, p\mid n,p\in \mathbb{G}}p^{v_p(n)}$ for a natural number $k$ or $k=0$.

Question 2:
If the g-number $n$ is of the form
$$n = 1+2^{2k} \prod_{q \neq 2, q\mid n-1,q \in \mathbb{G}} q^{v_q(n-1)}$$
with $k$ being a natural number and all $q$-s are g-numbers. Is then $n$  necessarily a prime number?
A naïve strategy for question 1: First prove 2 then use an inductive reasoning similar to Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes to conclude 1.
Edit: The only $u$-prime is $2$. Since there are infinitely many primes, not both classes $\mathbb{G}$, $\mathbb{M}$ can contain only finitely many primes. Hence at least one of the class $\mathbb{G}$ or $\mathbb{M}$ must contain infinitely many primes. Since the $m$-primes seem to be more frequent in number, maybe it is easier to ask:  Are there infinitely many $m$ -primes?
By the comment of @JonathanLove:
There are infinitely many $m$-primes: By the theorem of Dirichlet, there exist infinitely many primes of the form $p=1+3k$. But then $$f_p(x) = f_{3k}(x)+1=f_3(x) \cdot f_k(x)+1 = (x+1)f_k(x)+1$$
hence:
$$f_p(1)>1 = f_p(-1)>-1=-f_p(-1)$$
so each of these primes is an $m$-prime.
Edit: A maybe better way to genearte $g$-primes is this:
Question 4:
If $p>2$ and $f_p(x^2) = f_{f_p(4)}(x)$ then $q:=f_p(4)$ is a prime and a $g$-number?
Because of $x^2$ it is clear, that $q$ is a g-number, but why is it prime?
Here a short empirical evidence with sagemath:
 var("x")
for p in primes(1,10**5):
    R = QQ[x]
    #if R(ff(p,x^2)).is_irreducible():
    #   print(p)
    m = 4
    if ff(p,ff(m,x))==ff(ff(p,m),x):
        print(p,factor(int(ff(p,m))),getType(ff(p,m))) 
2 2^2 G
3 5 G
5 17 G
17 257 G
19 101 G
37 401 G
61 1361 G
73 1601 G
191 6869 G
229 8081 G
257 65537 G
271 8501 G
409 82241 G
457 32321 G
733 108881 G
1297 160001 G
1459 62501 G
1543 1310741 G
1627 170021 G

UPDATE:
Update: Here is an idea which uses Euler Product:

The goal is to show that there are infinitely many primes in a particular subset of natural numbers, $S_4$, by linking an (apparent) divergent series to an Euler product. In short, the steps are:

Define $S_4 \subset \mathbb{N}$ so that $f_n(x)$ has a special property.
Observe that $S_4$ is \emph{multiplicative} (if $a, b \in S_4$, then $a \cdot b \in S_4$).
Form an Euler product from an associated Dirichlet series over $S_4$.
Argue that if the Dirichlet series diverges at some $s > 0$, then infinitely many primes must lie in $S_4$.
Conclude from an additional property that those primes in $S_4$ are actually g-primes.

Below is a detailed explanation of each step.

1. Defining $S_4$
We define the set:
$$
S_4 = \bigl\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid f_{f_n(4)}(x) = f_n(x^2) \text{ for all real } x \bigr\}.
$$
In words:

$n \in S_4$ if and only if
$$
  f_{f_n(4)}(x) = f_n\bigl(x^2\bigr), \quad \text{for all } x.
  $$
Notably, from prior results, whenever $f_p(x^2) = f_{f_p(4)}(x)$ for $p > 2$ prime, it follows that $f_p(4)$ is itself a prime (and more specifically a g-prime).

Checking Some Base Cases

For $n = 1$, we have:
$$
  f_1(4) = 1, \quad f_1(x) = 1,
  $$
so $f_{f_1(4)}(x) = f_1(x) = 1$ and $f_1(x^2) = 1$. Thus, $1 \in S_4$.
Empirically, other numbers in $S_4$ include primes $p$ where $f_p(x^2) = f_{f_p(4)}(x)$.


2. The Multiplicative Property of $S_4$
We claim: if $a, b \in S_4$, then $a \cdot b \in S_4$.

Reasoning: If $a \in S_4$, then
$$
  f_{f_a(4)}(x) = f_a\bigl(x^2\bigr).
  $$
Similarly, for $b \in S_4$,
$$
  f_{f_b(4)}(x) = f_b\bigl(x^2\bigr).
  $$
For the product $n = a \cdot b$, we need to show:
$$
  f_{f_{a \cdot b}(4)}(x) = f_{a \cdot b}\bigl(x^2\bigr).
  $$
Since $f_{m \cdot n}(x)$ is built multiplicatively from $f_m(x)$ and $f_n(x)$, the property $f_{f_n(4)}(x) = f_n(x^2)$ extends naturally to the product $a \cdot b$, provided $a, b \in S_4$.

Thus, $S_4$ is \emph{multiplicative}.

3. Forming a Dirichlet Series over $S_4$
Now, consider the series:
$$
\sum_{n \in S_4} \frac{1}{n^s}, \quad (\text{for some real } s > 0).
$$
3.1. Euler Product from Multiplicativity
Since $S_4$ is multiplicative, we can express this series as an Euler product over the primes in $S_4$:
$$
\sum_{n \in S_4} \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{\substack{p \in S_4 \\ p \text{ prime}}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}.
$$
This follows from the fact that any $n \in S_4$ has a unique factorization in terms of the primes within $S_4$. The reasoning is the same as for the classical Euler product over all primes:
$$
\zeta(s) = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}},
$$
but restricted to the primes in $S_4$.

4. Divergence Argument $\implies$ Infinitely Many Primes in $S_4$
To show that $S_4$ contains infinitely many primes, it suffices to prove that the series
$$
\sum_{n \in S_4} \frac{1}{n^s}
$$
diverges for some $s > 0$. If the series diverges, then the product
$$
\prod_{\substack{p \in S_4 \\ p \text{ prime}}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}
$$
must also diverge, implying that there are infinitely many primes $p \in S_4$. This follows because if there were only finitely many primes in $S_4$, the product would converge.

5. Connecting to g-Primes
Finally, we observe:

For each $p \in S_4$, the property $f_p(x^2) = f_{f_p(4)}(x)$ implies that $q = f_p(4)$ is a g-prime.
If there are infinitely many primes in $S_4$, then there are infinitely many (potentially distinct) g-primes $q = f_p(4)$.

Thus, the infinitude of primes in $S_4$ implies the infinitude of g-primes.

6. Caveats and Next Steps

Verifying Divergence:

Empirically, the series
$$
 \sum_{n \in S_4} \frac{1}{n^s}
 $$
appears to diverge at $s = 1$. To make this rigorous, one needs to establish the density of $S_4$ or find a lower bound on its growth rate. This is typically the hardest part of such arguments.
For classical $\zeta(s)$, the series diverges if $s \leq 1$. For a multiplicative subset like $S_4$, the divergence depends on the distribution of its elements.


Ensuring Uniqueness:

To confirm the Euler product, we must ensure that every $n \in S_4$ factors uniquely over primes in $S_4$. This is likely true by definition, but it should be explicitly verified.




7. Summary of the Revised Idea

Define $S_4$ as:
$$
   S_4 = \bigl\{n \in \mathbb{N} : f_{f_n(4)}(x) = f_n(x^2)\text{ for all }x \bigr\}.
   $$
Verify that $S_4$ is multiplicative, i.e., if $a, b \in S_4$, then $ab \in S_4$.
Express the series over $S_4$ as:
$$
   \sum_{n \in S_4} \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{\substack{p \in S_4 \\ p \text{ prime}}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}.
   $$
Prove that the series diverges for some $s > 0$, implying infinitely many primes in $S_4$.
Conclude that $f_p(4)$ produces infinitely many g-primes.


Final Remarks
The core challenge is rigorously proving the divergence of $\sum_{n \in S_4} 1/n^s$. Once this is established, the Euler product ensures that there are infinitely many primes in $S_4$, leading to infinitely many g-primes as a corollary.

To the question in the edit: there are infinitely many primes $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$ by Dirichlet's theorem, and these are all m-primes because $f_p(1)>1=f_p(-1)$.

@JonathanLove: Thanks for your insight in this question. I updated the question with your proof.

related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484349/are-most-prime-numbers-symmetric

I want to answer Question 4. in the edit and hope it is Ok to use ChatGpt for Latex  writing:
The goal of the proof is to show that $q = f_p(4)$ must be prime. The key steps are:

Assume $q$ is composite, say $q = r \cdot s$ with $r, s > 1$.
Because $q$ is an odd g-number, both $r$ and $s$ must also be g-numbers. This implies:
$$
   f_r(x) = G(x^2), \quad f_s(x) = H(x^2),
   $$
where $G, H \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ are some polynomials, since $f_r,f_s$ are even polynomials.
The factorization $f_q(x) = f_{r \cdot s}(x)=f_r(x) \cdot f_s(x)$ then becomes:
$$
   f_q(x) = G(x^2) \cdot H(x^2).
   $$
Since $f_p(x^2) = f_q(x)$, we have:
$$
   f_p(x^2) = G(x^2) \cdot H(x^2).
   $$
Substituting $y = x^2$, this gives:
$$
   f_p(y) = G(y) \cdot H(y),
   $$
which is a nontrivial factorization of $f_p(y)$.

For $p > 2, p \text{ prime}$, $f_p(y)$ is irreducible, so this factorization is impossible. Thus, $q$ cannot be composite, and $q$ must be prime.
If $p = 2$, $f_2(x^2) = x^2$, and no contradiction arises because $f_2$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ after substitution $x \to x^2$.
